# Validate field in model with no table (CakePHP)

Tags: php, cakephp

I've got a model in CakePHP that doesn't have a table, called Upload. I've got a validation in this Model for a field called source_id.

I've got a form that builds a nice looking $this-data, giving me a well formated set, including:

```
$this->data['Upload']['source_id']
```

However, the validation rule I have set doesn't seem to run at all. I copied this validation rule from another model where it does work, so I'm confident that it works:

```
var $validate = array(
        'source_id' => array(
        rule' => 'numeric',
        'required' => true,
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message' => 'Error!.'
    )
);
```

Can you not validate fields for a model that lacks a database table?

The form uses the Upload model, and submits to another controller action method.

CakePHP 1.2, PHP/MySQL 5, XAMPP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm dumb. You have to trigger a validation check, either with a save() or

```
$this->Upload->set($this->data);
$this->Upload->validates();
```

Working now.

Answer (score 4):

You can also *fake* the database structure by setting the $_schema array, like so:

```
var $useTable = false;

var $_schema = array(
    'name'   =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>100), 
    'email' =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>255), 
    'phone' =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>20),
    'subject'  =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>255),
    'message'  =>array('type'=>'text')
);
```